# cancel server side submit funcion in asp.net with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I also made this question before but the problems remains here:

I have this code:

```
<asp:Button ID="CrearCuenta" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return validate()" runat="server" Text="Ready" />
```

The javascript code:

```
function validate()
{
return false;
}
```

But in case that it return true, **how do i execute de server side onclick function??** Thats what i cannot figure out. 
I know that similars question have been posted before, but none answer the question above.

Comment: Ive re-read this 5 times and still cant find a question.

Comment: Done, now its easier to find it

Comment: you need to add logic to validate function....otherwise submit will never work.....

Comment: It has it. it returns false if the validation fail. Ive tried athousands times and returns false if fails. So, whats the problem?

Comment: @Arun you were right, i miss something and it wasnt retuning anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope, here is what you need:

```
<asp:Button ID="CrearCuenta" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
OnClientClick="return validate()" OnClick="CrearCuenta_Click" 
runat="server" Text="Ready" />
```

Javascript:

```
function validate()
{
    if()
        return false;  //if validation fails
    else
        return true;
}
```

Server Side:

```
protected void CrearCuenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Put server side processing here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the server side event handler?

In your page code:

```
<asp:Button ID="CrearCuenta" OnClick="btn_Click"....
```

In your code-behind:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I didnt not that the onclick property could be different from the ID value

Answer (score 0):

check  this code

```
document.getElementById('YourFrom').onsubmit = function() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so, that mean that the asp button could be a normal button, right? no a server side button